# How do I keep my app from going inactive?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

In my manifest I have:

```
"app": 
{
    "background": 
    {
        "scripts": 
        [
            "main.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    }
}
```

but it still shows `Inspect views: _generated_background_page.html (Inactive)` and when I look at the console, it *is* inactive.

And I also have a `setInterval` running every 10 seconds. Yet, it still goes inactive!

What do I need to do to keep it from going inactive?

**Additional Info:**

I added an alarm that fires every minute and this *appears* to wake my app up. (Need to do more testing) But it means waiting a minute after Chrome startup before the app runs.

Comment: Apps cannot have persistent background pages so this is generally not possible. Why do you want you app to stay active?

Comment: It is a helper for other apps and keeps track of stuff and notifies them when those things occur. That way the other apps can all use the functionality without needing to include it themselves. They simply listen for an external message. But if it goes to sleep, it cannot do "push" notifications.

Comment: You mean that it listens to chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal (or onConnectExternal)? When a message comes, the event page will be started if it's not already active.

Comment: @方觉 no, I mean it listens to a web service via Ajax (in a `setInterval` and then uses `sendMessage( otherAppId, ... )` to notify other apps about what the web service says. But if it's inactive, it won't be checking with the web service and `sendMessage()` never gets called.

Comment: I think the alarm is a good idea. You might also try installing an extension with a real background page that "alarms" the app frequently by sending the app a message.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to have your web service host the helper app, and notify the other apps as necessary.  This seems the most "chromium" way (whatever that means).  But that would involve an app on one computer messaging an app on another computer, which seems complicated, at best.

You could also try `"permissions": ["background"]` ([reference](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/declare_permissions.html)).

It appears extensions are allowed persistent background pages, whereas apps aren't.  You could change your helper app into a helper extension that messages the other apps.

Answer (score -3):

Run your code when it needs to run, you don't need a background page running constantly to do so. E.g. use [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/runtime.html#event-onInstalled), [chrome.runtime.onStartup](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/runtime.html#event-onStartup), [chrome.app.runtime.onRestarted](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app.runtime.html#event-onRestarted), etc to trigger code on those events. The [Alarms API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/alarms.html) to wake up occasionally, [Push Messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/pushMessaging.html) to be woken up by your sever, or launch a window if there is interface a user should interact with.

The application can be restarted at any time - so always keep your state saved.

Comment: The three event listeners you listed do not fire when Chrome is restarted (after being fully shutdown). So my app remains inactive. I **need** it to always be running when Chrome is running. And push messaging won't work. This is a company-internal hosted app and the docs state: `"The Push Messaging server responds with HTTP status code 500 (internal server error) if the app that calls the pushMessaging API is not found in the Chrome Web Store."`

Comment: I apologize if this sounds harsh but your comment "you don't need a background page running constantly to do so" is very presumptive and unhelpful. You don't know what the requirements on my app are (although if you'd read my comments above, you would). I actually do need it to run constantly in the background.

Comment: Works for me. Take the window-state sample from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/window-state and in background.js duplicate onLaunched to chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener (NOT chrome.app.runtime). Exit chrome, restart, the window appears. (I tested on linux). If it doesn't work for you, file a bug: crbug.com/new

Comment: thanks for doing this. Just to check, when you tested this did you: 1. Shutdown Chrome (including from the taskbar for offline apps) and/or the computer, 2. Wait at least 5-10 minutes? I found if I restart Chrome quickly my app is not inactive on start.

Comment: I restarted by using 'Exit' from the Chrome menu, and by going to about:flags - flipping an option on and off - and using the Restart button on that page. I did not wait an extended amount of time or restart the computer. If apps don't launch in those scenarios with onStartup it is a bug, please file at crbug.com/new